# Como troca o valor do Select - Materil UI

Tags: javascript, react, material-ui

Olá, gostaria de saber setar um valor no Select component, do Material UI, atráves de um click?
Por exemplo, ao clicar no botão, invocar a funcao handleAlert, que troca o valor do Select;

```
export default function NativeSelects() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setState] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = event => {
    const name = event.target.value;
    setState(name);
  };

  const handleAlert = () => {
    const teste = 'teste'
    setState(teste);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          native
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "teste"
          }}
        >
          <option aria-label="None" value="teste" />
          <option value={10}>Ten</option>
          <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
          <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <Button onClick={handleAlert}>Teste</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, exemplo minimo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(3);
  const handleChangeValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <p>{value}</p>
        <Select defaultValue={value} onChange={handleChangeValue}>
          <MenuItem value="1">Primeiro Termo</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="2">Segundo Termo</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="3">Terceiro Termo</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="4">Quarto Termo</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Eu percebi que utilizou diferente, mas, eu fui [pela documentação e segui o exemplo](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) e um fato importante é utilizar dessa forma para ter o mesmo efeito mostrado no [site e na documentação](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/)